# Submenu not displayed exactly under parentmenu onmouseover

Tags: css

here is css
in this css i have #menu as ID of Main Menu Ul
i made change in display properrty but not any expected effect

```
/*Initialize*/

#menu
{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;   
    width:100%;
    left:auto;
    background-color:Gray;
 }
 ul#menu li ul.sub-menu 
{
    position:absolute;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    visibility:hidden;
    top: 30px; height:25px;  padding:5px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:none;display: none;    
}

#menu li 
{   position:relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:Olive;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    line-height:30px;  
    list-style-type: none;
    display:  block;
    float: left;
}




   ul#menu ul.sub-menu li 
   {
    float:left;
    line-height:30px; 
    text-indent:0;
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    list-style-type:none;
    clear:both;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border:none;
    display: table-cell;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    float: none;
    }

ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu  
{
     visibility:visible;  clear:both; /*display:inline;*/ position: absolute; display:table-cell; 

}

    ul#menu li a
    {
        display:block;text-indent:0; text-decoration: none; padding:5px 25px 5px 10px; 
    }

ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    display:inline-block; 
}
  ul#menu li a:hover ul.sub-menu 
  {
     visibility :visible;
     text-indent:0;
     font-size:20px;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     background-color:red;
     text-decoration: none;
     display:block;
   }
```

submenu will not display exactly under parent menu
I am very new to CSS and it's all control..guide me plz

Comment: Make jsfiddle OR give URL.

Comment: Sorry I am Dynamically generate menu
so unable to make fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `left` and `top` property

```
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
  position:absolute;
  clear:both;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  visibility:hidden;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0%; 
  height:25px;  
  padding:5px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display:none;    
}
```

Comment: yes sir its working now
but the sub menu size  will not display as menu size
it acquire less size than menu size
hope i make it clear